# Multigroup frequency with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to [replicate this histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ytW.png) in R.

Here is how to mock my dataset:

```
    dft <- data.frame(
  menutype =  sample(c(1,2,4,5,6,8,12), 120, replace = T),
  Belief = sample(c(0,1), 120, replace = T),
  Choice = sample(c(0,1), 120, replace = T)
)
```

Here is my code :

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(MASS)


    df <- data.frame(
  menutype =  factor(df$menutype, labels = c("GUILT" , "SSB0", "SSB1", "FLEX0", "FLEX1", "STD", "FLEX01"),
                     levels = c(1,2,4,5,6,8,12)),
  Belief = factor(df$belieflearn, levels = c(1), labels= c("Believe Learn")), #Interested only in this condition
  Choice = factor(df$learned, levels = c(1), labels= c("Learn")) #Same here
)


    df1 <- rbind(na.omit(df %>%
                           count(Belief, menutype) %>%
                           group_by(menutype) %>% 
                           mutate(prop = n / sum(n))),
                 na.omit(df %>%
                           count(Choice, menutype) %>%
                           group_by(menutype) %>% 
                           mutate(prop = n / sum(n))))



    test <- paste(df1$Belief[1:6],paste(df1$Choice[7:13]))
test[1:6] <- paste(df1$Belief[1:6])
test[7:13] <- paste(df1$Choice[7:13])

df1$combine <- paste(test)

    ggplot(data = df1, aes(menutype, prop, fill = combine)) + 
      labs(title = "Classification based on rank ordering\n", x = "", y = "Fraction of subjects", fill = "\n") +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
      theme_bw() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) #Centering of the main title+
    #geom_text(aes(label="ok"), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
```

The problem is that it's more or less working, I'm almost [getting the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoQjw.png) that I want but it is a workaround and there is still some errors. Indeed, I've for example the same value for STD (0.10), while it should be 0 and 0.10 like in the original graph.

What I would like to do optimally is to have two different dataframe, one with `menutype` and `Belief`, the other one with `menutype` and `Choice`, then as I did, compute the proportion of a specific modality in each latter variables on `menutype`, and finally to plot it as histograms, much as [the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ytW.png) in the original study. Additionally, I'd like to have the proportions as fractions above each bar, but that is optional.

Could someone help me on this matter? I'm really struggling to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I think the issue is with the `fill =`. I would like to specify for each bar the variable I want (e.g, `fill = df2$Belief & df2$Choice`) but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: We need some data in order to help you. You can create one table with all variables of interest, counts and percentages and then split your graphs using `facet_wrap` ( http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-facet-split-a-plot-into-a-matrix-of-panels ). You can use `geom_text` to show the fractions on top of your bars ( http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization ), but you have to create those fractions in another column as text.

Comment: Oh yeah! I'm sorry. Just edited my post. The thing is that I would like to have the two variables in the same graph, not splitted. But thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use your process from start to end, because there are some bugs.
However, I'll post something that will help you see how your dataset with all your stats needs to look like in order to plot they way you want in an easy way....

Comment: ....Note that my process is only an example. Yours will be more complicated, but the key thing here is to see that you need (a) your proportions, (b) the variable that will create the barplots, (c) the variable that will split your plots, (d) anything else you want to show on your plot in the same dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)

# example data frame
df <- data.frame(
  menutype =  sample(c(1,2,4,5,6,8,12), 120, replace = T),
  Belief = sample(c(0,1), 120, replace = T),
  Choice = sample(c(0,1), 120, replace = T)
)

# calculate all metrics based on all variables you want to plot in a tidy way
df_plot = df %>%
  group_by(Choice) %>%
  count(menutype, Belief) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n),
         prop_text = paste0(n, "/", sum(n))) %>%
  ungroup()

# barplots using one variable and split plots using another variable
df_plot %>%
  mutate(Belief = factor(Belief),
         menutype = factor(menutype)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(menutype, prop, fill = Belief))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~Choice, ncol=1)+
  geom_text(aes(label=prop_text), position = position_dodge(1), vjust = -0.5)+
  ylim(0,0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help, but what I'm trying to get is to have the two variables (Choice and Belief) on the same graph. In other words, that the blue bar is the proportion of "Belief' and the red the proportion of "Choice", for each menu type. But in any case, thanks a lot, I'll try to tweak your code to get to work for me.

Comment: This sounds like a column reshaping. In my example I'm using variable `Belief` with values `0` and `1`, but you should create a variable named `group` (or any name you want) with values `Choice` and `Belief`. Then you can plot in a similar way like my example above.

Comment: This will create a variable with a bigger length compared to your dataset. Also, the values will not be `Belive` and `Choice`, but the values of those columns. Try to find some reshaping functions from `tidyr`.